# What does the Latin place name 'Rezii' refer to?

Tags: place-names

I came across a book published in 1753 with the publisher location listed as '*Rezii*'. I cannot find any reference to this name online. [Here](http://www.worldcat.org/title/armatura-fortium-seu-loci-theologici-cum-annexis-conciliis-generalibus-breviter-et-ex-probatissimis-authoribus-historico-critice-delineatis-una-cum-centuria-thesium-ex-universa-theologia-scholastica-dogmatica-ad-mentem-angelici-et-quinti-ecclesiae-doctoris-d-thomae-aqunatis-compilatore-et-praeside-ludovico-ehenger-s-canonici-et-exempti-ord-praemonsti-rogiae-eccl-lucensis-canonico-regul-et-ss-theol-professore-actuali-defendente-ar-ac-rel-d-sebastiano-janco-ejusdem-canoniae-professo/oclc/444826018&referer=brief_results)  is a link to the book information.

The only libraries that have the book are located in Slovenia so maybe it refers to a town there?

Comment: I'm not sure if it is related at all, but there was a province called [Raetia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Raetia), in the Alps, not too far from Slovenia, after a Gaul tribe called [*raetii*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rhaetian_people). In the Ecclesiastical pronunciation, *ae* sounds like the *e*, and *ti* sounds like the Italian *zi*, so it may as well be a back-produced spelling. It would be quite odd if this were the explanation, though, because I would have expected to see a different ending like  *Reziae*. Probably just a red herring.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I did some research and it appears to be **Rötz** - see, for instance, [another treatise](http://explore.bl.uk/BLVU1:LSCOP-ALL:BLL01018030640) held by the British Library written by the same author and typeset (published?) by the same person as well:

[image]

cf. "Gedruckt zu Rötz bey Christoph Joseph Hueth, Wiennerischen Universitäts-Buchdrucker."

[image]

Finally, [this](https://books.google.com/books?id=0XpiAAAAcAAJ&dq=R%C3%B6tz%20%3A%20gedruckt%20bey%20Christoph%20Joseph%20Hueth&pg=PT1#v=onepage&q&f=false) confirms our hypothesis that Rötz is a town:

[image]

Some information on Rötz (its earlier name forms and etymology), from [an entry on Rötz (creek)](https://www.degruyter.com/view/books/9783110338591/9783110338591.421/9783110338591.421.xml):
[image]

The text you refer to:

[image]